# Spring Boot repository does not persist one-to-many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I have a Spring Boot app with JPA and H2 with two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Skill> skills = new HashSet<Skill>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "skills")
public class Skill {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "skill_id")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name="person_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Person person;
}
```

I have JPA repositories for the person entity:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

When I try to save the following object, it returns the correct entity with skills included immediately, but when I call `repository.find(<id-of-saved-entity>)`, the skills are empty (so they did not get persisted):

```
{ "name": "Test", "skills": [ { "name": "Skill1" }, { "name": "Skill2"} ] }
```

Could someone help me out and tell me what is wrong with my mapping and configuration?

Comment: if you do person.getSkills().size().. is the collection loaded?

Comment: @Smajl have you tried `@ElementCollection`

Comment: Did the `skills` got saved inside database?

Comment: Is there a reason you're specifying the column names?

Comment: @javaguy No, they did not. And if I try to access `person.getSkills()`, it says the collection is empty.

Comment: can you add the `FetchType` inside `Person` like `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` ?

Comment: @javaguy Does not work, unofrtunately, still empty\

Comment: I have the same problem. this is really strange.Sping Data JPA does not seem to persist the relations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for spring data REST (HATEOAS) repositories. They say, you have to send a PUT request to the association resource that contains the URI of the [parent] resource

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/libraries/1" http://localhost:8080/books/1/library
```

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

I hope the link helps.